The space of cuspidal elements $L_{0}^2(GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A),\omega)$ is a closed subspace of $L^2(GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A),\omega)$.
Let $F$ be an algebraic number field, $A$ its adele ring. Let $\omega$ be a unitary character, that is, a continuous group homomorphism $\omega:A^\times/F^\times\rightarrow C^\times$.
Let $L^2(GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A),\omega)$ be the space of measurable function on $GL(n,A)$ with respect to Haar measure and that satisfy
$$\phi\left(\left(
\begin{matrix}
z & 0 \\
0 & z \\
\end{matrix}
\right)g\right)=\omega(z)\phi(g),\ \ \ \ \ z\in A^\times,$$
$$\phi(\gamma g)=\phi(g),\ \ \ \ \ \gamma\in GL(2,F),$$
and the square integrable modulo the center:
$$\int_{Z(A)GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A)}|\phi(g)|^2 dg<\infty,$$
which induces the norm on $L^2(GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A),\omega)$, that is $\|\phi\|=(\int_{Z(A)GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A)}|\phi(g)|^2 dg)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.
Let $L_{0}^2(GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A),\omega)=\left\{\phi\in L^2(GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A),\omega):\int_{F\backslash A}\phi\left(\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & x \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}\right)g\right) dx=0, \text{ for all $g\in GL(n,A)$}\right\}$,
consists of cuspidal elements in $L^2(GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A),\omega)$.
I want to prove that $L_{0}^2(GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A),\omega)$ is a closed subspace of $L^2(GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A),\omega)$. It suffices to prove that the map $\psi:L_{0}^2(GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A),\omega)\rightarrow\mathbf{R}_{\geq 0}\cup\{\infty\}$ defined as $\psi(\phi):=\int_{F\backslash A}\phi\left(\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & x \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}\right)g\right) dx$ is continuous.
Thus, given $\epsilon>0$, I have problem on determining the $\delta>0$ such that if $\|\phi_1-\phi_2\|<\delta$, then $\left|\int_{F\backslash A}\phi_1\left(\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & x \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}\right)g\right) dx-\int_{F\backslash A}\phi_2\left(\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & x \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}\right)g\right) dx\right|<\epsilon$
